# SSIS Format Text column to Currency to show $

Tags: ssis

I am trying to move data from Source excel to Destination excel. However I need to do some formatting before I can move data. Most important conversions are string to currency so that I can have $ sign and then Date should be in the format of yyyy-mm-dd. Below is the example of data in source

```
<br/>
ID  Amount  Date<br/>
A1  10.01   10/25/2016<br/>
A2  100.3   10/26/2016<br/>
```

Format that I am trying to load into Destination Excel

```
ID    Amount     Date<br/>
A1  **$10.01**   2016/10/26<br/>
A2  **$100.30**  2016/10/26<br/>
```

Any Help? Thanks much.

**UPDATE:** IT IS REQUIREMENT THAT THE OUTPUT COLUMN IN EXCEL BE OF CURRENCY TYPE NOT TEXT.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a Derived column task, concatenate a "$" to the value before passing it to the Excel destination? Data type as string in the derived column using an expression like follows:

```
'$' + columnWithDollarValue
```

MSDN reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms138036.aspx

Comment: I already tried this but clients want the column to be in currency format not text.

Comment: Using this will convert the column to TEXT. And client doesnt want this.

Answer (score 0):

add a script component mark the 2 columns as input and create to output columns:
`outDate` and `outCurrency`

in the script write the following code:

```
if not Row.Date_ISNull AndAlso not string.isnullorEmpty(Row.Date)
row.outDate = Date.ParseExact(Row.Date,"MM/dd/yyyy", new system.globalization.cultureinfo("en-GB"),none).tostring("yyyy/MM/dd")
else
 row.outDate_IsNull = True

end if


If not row.Currency_IsNUll andAlso not string.isnullorEmpty(row.Currency) Then
row.outcurrency = "$" & Row.Currency
else
Row.outCurrency_IsNull = True
end if
```

And Map the output Column to the Destination Excel

If you want the column in currency format it must be changed from the excel file. Or you have to change it using script task using excel manipulation library like `microsoft.office.interop.excel` or `OpenXML`